# How to preview and print in PDF a markdown file with a file-specific CSS stylesheet in VS Code?

Tags: css, visual-studio-code, markdown

Here is my use case:

I want to create a markdown document (my CV for instance) and create a style for it using a CSS file. Then I want to print the PDF of my file.

I have installed the `Markdown PDF` extension in VS Code and it does its job.

To have the extension and the preview to properly render the styling, I changed the settings in vscode `setting.json` for both extensions to use my CSS file and it works.

For the preview:

```
{
  "markdown.styles": ["my-styles.css"]
}
```

For the PDF export:

```
{
  "markdown-pdf.styles": ["~/Documents/Styles/my-styles.css"]
}
```

However, this stylesheet is applied to *all* my markdown files and what I would like is to embed the CSS file for this specific file. I want to have a CV style for my CVs, a report style for reports, etc.

Is this feasible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [workspace specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/multi-root-workspaces#_settings) solves my issue.

It does not allow to use one CSS per markdown file, but it's good enough: I can put all my CVs in one folder with the CV CSS in the workspace settings and my reports in another workspace with another CSS stylesheet